# visual basic 5 run-time error 429 dbengine.workspaces

Tags: vb5

I had an application perfectly working under Windows XP (32 bit). Moving to Windows 7 (64 bit) and compiling gives me the error `run time error 429 ActiveX component can't create object` in the module *(second line, "set mydb=...", see code)* where I make the connection with the MS Access database (Access 2013 in Windows 7 64 bit). In Windows XP it was an Access 2000 database with extension `.mdb`. Now it is Access 2013 with extension `.accdb`.

In the references I replaced the Microsoft Office DAO 3.5 library with the Microsoft Office 15.0 Access Database Engine Object Library, but this doesn't solve the problem. (If I leave the DAO object library, then I get `run time error 3343 unrecognized database format` on the same line.)

I'm not sure if I have to put in the components of the forms the 32 or the 64 bit version. (For example, dbrgid32.ocx under windows\system32 or under windows\sysWOW64 ... or does it not matter?)

```
Sub pldata()
Set mydb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("D:\ETC\Gegevens\ETC2015.accdb", False, False, "MS Access")
'Set mydb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("D:\ETC\Gegevens\ETC2015.accdb")ess")
Set myrstadres = mydb.OpenRecordset("select * from dbadres order by naam")
End Sub
```

Comment: There seems to be something odd about the second set mydb line ... why is that `ess")` tacked on there?

Comment: this is a comment line, so that can not be the problem...